Openai whisper error with cmd and Google Colaboratory ("Traceback"...)
I tried to install whisper, but I am getting the error messages (below) with Command Line and even with Google Colaboratory (Google Drive). I tried mp4, mp3 and wav files, but I always get error messages.
Here is what I get with Google Colaboratory:
!whisper "teste.mp3" --model medium

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/whisper/audio.py", line 58, in load_audio
    out = run(cmd, capture_output=True, check=True).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ffmpeg', '-nostdin', '-threads', '0', '-i', 'teste.mp3', '-f', 's16le', '-ac', '1', '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', '-ar', '16000', '-']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 597, in cli
    result = transcribe(model, audio_path, temperature=temperature, **args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 133, in transcribe
    mel = log_mel_spectrogram(audio, model.dims.n_mels, padding=N_SAMPLES)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/whisper/audio.py", line 140, in log_mel_spectrogram
    audio = load_audio(audio)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/whisper/audio.py", line 60, in load_audio
    raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to load audio: {e.stderr.decode()}") from e
RuntimeError: Failed to load audio: ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
teste.mp3: No such file or directory

Skipping teste.mp3 due to RuntimeError: Failed to load audio: ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
teste.mp3: No such file or directory

Here is what I get with Command Prompt: ("cmd" in the same folder as the file)
whisper "teste.mp3"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Waleson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Waleson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Waleson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\whisper.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Waleson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\whisper\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Users\Waleson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 148, in <module>
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\Waleson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

I followed YouTube tutorials and read some posts here, but nothing works. (I don't understand much)

The fix is to replace typographic quotes with straight quotes in the file name.
In your case, replace "teste.mp3" with 'teste.mp3'.
Straight quotes.
